# change jquery function parameter with another jquery function

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to change a jquery function's parameter with another jquery function?

What I have is this (stripped down):

```
$(".jThumbnailScroller").thumbnailScroller({
        scrollerType: "hoverPrecise"
});
```

And I'm wondering if I can change scrollerType: "hoverPrecise" to "clickButtons" via another function that gets called after detecting mobile?

Thanks!

Comment: That completely depends on how the plugin works.  Check their docs for a change method, or submit a pull request.

Comment: You should at least link to the plugin. Are you sure it does not have documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Have you at least try:

```
$(".jThumbnailScroller").thumbnailScroller('option','scrollerType','clickButtons');
```

Comment: Yes, this is how many jqueryui (if not all) plugins work, they let you change specific options after it is called. It would be wise for the author of the plugin to do the same thing. If not, then why can't you detect if it is mobile FIRST, and then change your parameter?